# Essential difference between Servlet context and Spring application context

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I'm reading the spring framework documentation and now I'm at [application scope concept](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-application). What the documentation says about that concept is this:

> This is somewhat similar to a Spring singleton bean but differs in two
>   important ways: It is a singleton per ServletContext, not per Spring
>   ApplicationContext

To me, what's unclear is how can we imagine the relationship between Spring application context and Servlet context.

I'd assume that there two possible cases for the relationship between them:

***I***

[image]

***II***

[image]

So, how does the Spring application context relate with Servlet context? Is it case ***I*** or case ***II*** or neither of them?

Comment: @BalusC According to your comment. What does Spring application context != Application context? What did you mean?

Comment: The programming term "Application Context" is ambiguous as it applies on other frameworks as well, it is not per definition "Spring Application Context". I just edited the question so that it's more explicit in that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's neither of them.

ServletContext is the standard Java EE *application* scope. Each deployed webapp has one and only one servlet context.

Inside this webapp, you can have one (typically) or several Spring application contexts: one per Spring-MVC dispatcher servlet.

Comment: Thank for that answer, but I'd like to make some clarifaction about other details. As known, singleton scoped spring beans are unique per ApplicationContext. __GoF Singleton__, in turn, assumes that the instance is unique per __ClassLoader__. How does __Servlet Context__ relate to the __ClassLoader__? I mean what's "bigger"?

Comment: The ClassLoader is "bigger". In a Java EE container, each webapp has its own ClassLoader, that loads classes from WEB-INF/classes and the jars inside WEB-INF/lib. Singleton here doesn't really relate to the classical GoF (anti-)pattern. It just means: there is only one instance of the bean in the application context.